# Handling Unicode string pulled from SOQL In Python

Tags: python, unicode, ascii, soql

The purpose of the code is to use SOQL to query the SalesForce API, then to format the data and do some stuff before putting putting it into an oracle database. My code successfully handles the first and third part but the second part keeps breaking.

The code is using Python 2.7 with the standard C python compiler on Windows 7.

The SOQL is

```
SELECT  ID, Name, Type, Description, StartDate, EndDate, Status
FROM        CAMPAIGN
ORDER BY    ID
```

This query pulls back a few hundred results in a JSON Dict.
I have to pull each record (Record contains ID, Name, Type, Description, StartDate, EndDate, and Status) one at a time and pass them to a function that generates the proper SQL to put the data in the proper Oracle Database. All of the results of the query come back as Unicode strings.

After I query the data and try to pass it to the function to generate the SQL to insert it into the Oracle database is where the trouble shows up.

Here is the section of code where the error occurs.

```
keys = ['attributes', 'Id', 'Name', 'Type', 'Description', 'StartDate', 'EndDate', 'Status']
for record in SrcData['records']:  #Data cleaning in this loop. 
    processedRecs = []
    if record['Description'] is not None:                
        record['Description'] = encodeStr(record['Description'])
        record['Description'] = record['Description'][0:253]

    for key in keys:
        if key == 'attributes':
            continue
        elif key == 'StartDate' and record[key] is not None:
            record[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(record[key], "%Y-%m-%d")
        elif key == 'EndDate' and record[key] is not None:
            record[key] = datetime.datetime.strptime(record[key], "%Y-%m-%d")
        else:
            pass

        processedRecs.append(record[key])

    sqlFile.seek(0)
    Query = RetrieveSQL(sqlFile, processedRecs)
```

The key list is because there was issues with looping on SrcData.keys().
the encodeStr function is:

```
def encodeStr(strToEncode):
    if strToEncode == None:
        return ""
    else:
        try:
            tmpstr = strToEncode.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
            tmpstr = ' '.join(tmpstr.split())
            return tmpstr 
        except:
            return str(strToEncode)
```

The error message I get is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last): File "XXX", line 106, in Query = ASPythonLib.RetrieveSQL(sqlFile, processedRecs), UnicodeEncodeError: ascii codec cant encode character u\u2026 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)
```

the XXXX is just a file path to where this code is in our file system. Boss said I must remove the path.

I have also tried multiple variation of:

```
record['Description'] = record['Description'].encode('ascii', 'ignore').decode(encoding='ascii',errors='strict')
```

I have tried swapping the order of the encode and decode functions. I have tried different codecs and different error handling schemes.

****Edit**** This code works correct in like 20 other cycles so it's safe to assume the error is not in the RetrieveSQL().
Here is the code for RetrieveSQL:

```
def RetrieveSQL(SQLFile, VarList, Log = None):
    SQLQuery = SQLFile.readline()

    FileArgs = [""]

    NumArgValues = len(VarList)

    if( "{}" in SQLQuery ):
        # NumFileArgs == 0
        if (NumArgValues != 0):
            print "Number of File Arguments is zero for File " + str(SQLFile) + " is NOT equal to the number of values provided per argument (" + str(NumArgValues) + ")."
        return SQLFile.read()
    elif( SQLQuery[0] != "{" ):
        print "File " + str(SQLFile) + " is not an SQL source file."
        return -1

    elif( SQLQuery.startswith("{") ):
        FileArgs = SQLQuery.replace("{", "").replace("}", "").split(", ")
        for Arg in xrange(0, len(FileArgs)):
            FileArgs[Arg] = "&" + FileArgs[Arg].replace("\n", "").replace("\t", "") + "&" # Add &'s for replacing

    NumFileArgs  = len(FileArgs)

    if (NumFileArgs != NumArgValues):
        if (NumArgValues == 0):
            print "No values were supplied to RetrieveSQL() for File " + str(SQLFile) + " when there were supposed to be " + str(NumFileArgs) + " values."
            return -1
        elif (NumArgValues > 0):
            "Number of File Arguments (" + str(NumFileArgs) + ") for File " + str(SQLFile) + " is NOT equal to the number of values provided per argument (" + str(NumArgValues) + ")."
            return -1

    SQLQuery = SQLFile.read()
    VarList = list(VarList)
    for Arg in xrange(0, len(FileArgs)):
            if (VarList[Arg] == None):
                SQLQuery = SQLQuery.replace(FileArgs[Arg], "NULL")
            elif ("'" in str(VarList[Arg])):
                SQLQuery = SQLQuery.replace(FileArgs[Arg], "'" + VarList[Arg].replace("'", "''") + "'")
            elif ("&" in str(VarList[Arg])):
                SQLQuery = SQLQuery.replace(FileArgs[Arg], "'" + VarList[Arg].replace("&", "&'||'") + "'")
            elif (isinstance(VarList[Arg], basestring) == True):
                VarList[Arg] = VarList[Arg].replace("'", "''")
                SQLQuery = SQLQuery.replace(FileArgs[Arg], "'" + VarList[Arg] + "'")
            else:
                SQLQuery = SQLQuery.replace(FileArgs[Arg], str(VarList[Arg]))
    SQLFile.seek(0)

    return SQLQuery
```

****Edit #2 ****
Tried finding a complete traceback in logging files but the logging system for this script is terrible and never logs more than 'Cycle success' or 'Cycle Fail'. Ahh the fun of rewriting code written by people who don't know how to code.

Comment: Is that a complete traceback? What is `RetrieveSQL` here?

Comment: Yes that is a complete traceback. RetrieveSQL is a function that generates SQL queries using a template sql file.

Comment: But that function is not implemented in C? Then your traceback would go *further*. The format is incomplete, there is no module or function named, there are no preceding lines, etc.

Comment: And you should not use a template to interpolate data into a SQL query; you want to use SQL parameters and leave interpolation to the database driver.

Comment: Please do show the actual traceback; the current information is not enough to diagnose the problem.

Comment: This is the full traceback as given by spyder.
Traceback (most recent call last): File "XXXXX", line 106, in Query = ASPythonLib.RetrieveSQL(sqlFile, processedRecs), UnicodeEncodeError: ascii codec cant encode character u\u2026 in position 31: ordinal not in range(128)

the XXXX is just a file path to where this code is in our file system. Boss said I must remove the path.

Comment: Sure, removing the path is fine. I'm just very surprised that the traceback doesn't reach into the `RetrieveSQL()` function, because that's just more Python code.

Comment: That would be nice. I am digging into log files to see if there is a more complete traceback but that is a straight copy paste from the spyder console.

Comment: In retriveSQL, you have a print statement containing this piece: `str(SQLFile)`. SQLFile is a file-like object? So the result would be something like `"<open file XXXX, mode 'rb' at 0x00000000022C1300>"`, with XXXX replaced by the full file path. Any chance this is causing the problem?

Comment: The retrieveSQL() works correctly. and yea sql file is
sqlFile = open(os.path.join(workingPath, 'SQL Queries', 'ThisCycle.txt' ))